# Why does the less-than sign not work as a replacement for cat in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, cat

I heard about "useless use of cat" and found some suggestions, but the following outputs nothing in my bash shell.

```
< filename
```

Using cat works as expected though.

```
cat filename
```

I'm using Fedora Core 18 and GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1).

EDIT: Using it in front of a pipe doesn't work either.

```
< filename | grep pattern
```

Whereas using cat works as expected.

```
cat filename | grep pattern
```

EDIT2: To clarify, I know that I can use this

```
grep pattern < filename
```

but I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat that I can also use it in front of the command. It does not work in front of the command though.

Comment: It works. Just what you tried is not the same as [Jonathan Leffler's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat#comment23911950_16619430) suggests.

Comment: "The purpose of cat is to concatenate (or "catenate") files. If it's only one file, concatenating it with nothing at all is a waste of time, and costs you a process." http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The less than and symbol (`<`) is opening the file up and attaching it to the standard input device handle of some application/program. But you haven't given the shell any application to attach the input to.

#### Example

These 2 examples do essentially the same thing but get their input in 2 slightly different manners.

*opens file*

```
$ cat blah.txt 
hi
```

*opens STDIN*

```
$ cat < blah.txt 
hi
```

#### Peeking behind the curtain

You can use `strace` to see what's going on.

*When we read from a file*

```
open("blah.txt", O_RDONLY)              = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3, ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, "hi\n", 65536)                  = 3
write(1, "hi\n", 3hi
)                     = 3
read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
```

*When we read from STDIN (identified as 0)*

```
read(0, "hi\n", 65536)                  = 3
write(1, "hi\n", 3hi
)                     = 3
read(0, "", 65536)                      = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
```

In the first example we can see that `cat` opened the file and read from it, `blah.txt`. In the second we can see that `cat` reads the contents of the file `blah.txt` via the STDIN file descriptor, identified as descriptor number 0.

```
read(0, "hi\n", 65536)                  = 3
```

Comment: So this talk about useless use of cat is bogus?

Comment: @bug - no,  there are uses. But `cat` is generally misunderstood and is used when it isn't necessary.

Comment: But it is necessary when I want to preserve the order of the operations from left to right? I read that it is possible to use the less-than construct in front of the command as well.

Comment: @bug yes the redirect can occur before or after the command, see Stephane's answer, he shows this example as well.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I'd have to write `< filename command`.

Answer (score 22):

The classic useless use of `cat` is when you use it to give input to programs that are perfectly capable of opening files directly. For example:

#### Bad

```
cat file | grep foo
cat file | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
cat file | sed 's/a/b/'
cat file | awk '{print $1}'
```

#### Good

```
grep foo file
while read line; do echo "$line"; done < file 
sed 's/a/b/' file
awk '{print $1}' file
```

#### Also good (the `<file` can be on either side of the command)

```
<file grep foo
 sed 's/a/b/' < file
<file awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: "Bad" is subjective here.  I find those to be better overall, because it is _way_ more consistent and easier to read.  And the flow of data is fully left-to-right, as it should be if there's more pipes involved

Comment: @Izkata they're "bad" in the sense that they are useless uses of `cat`.

Comment: Noteworthy good (or, at least, useful) uses of `cat` include  (1) `cat file` (with output to the screen/terminal; although, if the file is longer than the screen is high, you might prefer to use `more` or `less` or something like that),  (2) `cat file1 file2 file3 > all_data` (***exactly*** what `cat` is meant for),  (3) `cat f1 f2 f3 | tr …` (or pipe into any other program that you don’t want to pass the files to directly; e.g., `wc` (e.g., if you want to see the grand total only) or `grep` (e.g., if you have an old version that doesn’t support `-h`, i.e., `--no-filename`)),  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) `cat -n file | sort … -k1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]*\t//'`,  (5) `sudo cat file600 | untrusted_program` (i.e., *you* (your UID) can’t read the file, and you don’t want to run the program as root or even any semi-privileged UID).  Also, (*e*) (i.e., a number between 2 and 3) `program_that_generates_html | cat static_html_header - static_html_footer` (which you would *probably* want to redirect to a file or a pipe).

Answer (score 14):

The UUOC is in:

```
cat somefile | some-cmd
```

or

```
cat < somefile | some-cmd
```

There, `some-cmd` is reading the content of `somefile` from a pipe that is fed by `cat` which itself reads it from `somefile`.

`some-cmd` can read directly from `somefile` (after the shell has opened it for it on stdin), there's no need for `cat`:

```
some-cmd < somefile
```

or

```
< somefile some-cmd
```

(redirections can appear anywhere on a simple command line).