# Linux - Understanding an stdin/stdout command "<"

Tags: linux, io-redirection, command

I just started a short video course on Linux and kind of get the use and function of stdin and stdout. I saw on the course though that the instructor used `cat < [nameOfExecutable]`. I tried looking around though I can't seem to find what its call and what's for (possible due to my lack of fundamentals).

What is difference does it make adding the "<" symbol?

Let us say for example: `cat < [nameOfExecutable]` vs regular `cat [nameOfExecutable]`?

Comment: Thank you Jeff for editing my messages and helping me credit the correct person properly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question using slm’s response on this thread:
[Why does the less-than sign not work as a replacement for cat in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106039/why-does-the-less-than-sign-not-work-as-a-replacement-for-cat-in-bash)

Seeing what happens behind the curtain opened my eyes on what's really going on.